# PyTorch : cuda out of memory but enough memory left (add error message)

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to classify cat vs dog with GoogleNet(Pytorch).
Each class contains 4000 images to train and 1000 images to test, which's size is 300*300.
My computer has 32GB RAM and RTX 2080 Super graphic card.
And this error occurs when it just start to train. Below is my code the part of GoogleNet :

```py
class Inception(nn.Module) :
    def __init__(self, in_dim, out_dim1, mid_dim3, out_dim3, mid_dim5, out_dim5, pool):
       super(Inception, self).__init__()
        self.lay1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_dim, out_dim1, kernel_size= 1), nn.BatchNorm2d(out_dim1), nn.ReLU())
        self.lay2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_dim, mid_dim3, kernel_size = 1), nn.BatchNorm2d(mid_dim3), nn.ReLU(), nn.Conv2d(mid_dim3, out_dim3, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1), nn.BatchNorm2d(out_dim3), nn.ReLU())
        self.lay3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_dim, mid_dim5, kernel_size = 1), nn.BatchNorm2d(mid_dim5), nn.ReLU(), nn.Conv2d(mid_dim5, out_dim5, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1), nn.BatchNorm2d(out_dim5), nn.ReLU(), nn.Conv2d(out_dim5, out_dim5, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1), nn.BatchNorm2d(out_dim5), nn.ReLU())
        self.lay4 = nn.Sequential(nn.MaxPool2d(3, 1, 1), nn.Conv2d(in_dim, pool, kernel_size = 1), nn.BatchNorm2d(pool), nn.ReLU())

    def forward(self, x):
        y1 = self.lay1(x)
        y2 = self.lay2(x)
        y3 = self.lay3(x)
        y4 = self.lay4(x)

        return torch.cat([y1, y2, y3, y4], 1)


class Google(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Google, self).__init__()
        self.pre_lay = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1, 48, 3, padding = 1), nn.BatchNorm2d(48), nn.ReLU())
        self.glay1 = Inception(48, 16, 24, 32, 4, 8, 8)
        self.glay2 = Inception(64, 32, 32, 48, 8, 24, 16) # input channel : prev output channel sum(torch.cat)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride = 2, padding = 1)
        self.glay3 = Inception(120, 48, 24, 52, 4, 12, 16)
        self.glay4 = Inception(128, 40, 28, 56, 6, 16, 16)
        self.glay5 = Inception(128, 32, 32, 64, 6, 16, 16)
        self.glay6 = Inception(128, 28, 36, 72, 8, 16, 16)
        self.glay7 = Inception(132, 64, 40, 80, 8, 32, 32)
        self.glay8 = Inception(208, 64, 40, 80, 8, 32, 32)
        self.glay9 = Inception(208, 96, 48, 96, 12, 32, 32)


        self.avgpool = nn.AvgPool2d(8, stride = 1)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(47872, 2)
        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()


    def forward(self, x):
        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        # with torch.no_grad() : // 
            out = self.pre_lay(x) # CUDA out of memory Occurs!!
            out = self.glay1(out)
            out = self.glay2(out)
            out = self.maxpool(out)
            out = self.glay3(out)
            out = self.glay4(out)
            out = self.glay5(out)
            out = self.glay6(out)
            out = self.glay7(out)
            out = self.maxpool(out)
            out = self.glay8(out)
            out = self.glay9(out)
            out = self.avgpool(out)
            out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
            print("Out size : ", out.size())
            out = self.linear(out)

        return out
```

As I wrote, at the first step of GoogleNet the error occurs. Prior line of the error-occurs, someone suggested to add with torch.no_grad() : at model's forward function if there's cuda memory error but memory wasn't the issue. But then ***element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn*** error was out.
I tried empty_cache on every step I suspect that using GPU memory a lot, but still not working.

If anyone who've been similar error or know the reason, your advice must be very thankful.

## Add full error message

[cuda memory error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFxuL.png)

This is what I got with memory error.

[grad error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm6MH.png)

Below error was after I add torch.no_grad() at forward()

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? Normally pyorch says what and how much it tried to allocate and how much memory was left.

Comment: @Nopileos I add my error messages. It says Tried to allocate 1.25 GiB. Is it just memory issue? I thought my graphic card and RAM can handle 10K images and googlenet.

Answer (score 1):

"CUDA out of memory" is an error about the *GPU*, not the RAM. The error message says it needs 1.25 GB but only 1.16 GB free, so you don't have enough GPU memory.

To avoid this error, you can try using smaller batch size to reduce the memory usage on GPU. Also check for any "ghost" tensors in your Python process, that is the tensors that were allocated but no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get this error, but I have some suggestions that you can try.
you can create generator data loader function instead of handle all images on memory.